# What is wrong with my attempt to concatenate within an if statement

Tags: f#

I'm trying to concatenate leading 0s to the hundreds place.

```
    001 ones
    010 tens 
    100 hundreds

for i = 1 to 100
    let x = 
        if i < 10 then sprintf "Hello World 00%i" i
        elif (i >= 10) && (i < 100) then sprintf "Hello World 0%i" i
```

> Squigglies on the elif - The expression expected to have have unit but
>   it has string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that an `if` without an `else` must have type unit. That is, if you want your `if` to have a meaningful value (such as your concatenated string), it must have an `else`.

If you're wondering why, just ask yourself this: What would the value of `x` be when `i` is 100 or greater?